# Show login password as it is typed

Tags: keyboard, login, password

The keyboard on my 8 year-old laptop is becoming less reliable, often a keypress won't register first time and sometimes, if pressed too hard, will repeat. This is not a big deal except when logging into Ubuntu via the graphical login screen, because by default the login password is shown as asterisks and sometimes I enter the wrong password two or three times before having to resort to clicking on the eye to see what I have actually typed.

It would be very useful for me to have the actual keypresses shown at login, rather than asterisks, as default. Is this possible?

Comment: It depends where do you want the password to be visible. On graphical login screen? On text login screen (virtual terminal)? When logging in via ssh? On websites in browser? Each one probably will require a separate solution, as there is different software responsible for masking the password and different methods used.

Comment: I am referring to the graphical login screen. I have edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: The graphical login depends on the DE you have and/or the greeter you installed/changed to. Standard Ubuntu greeter shows an "eye" symbol at the rightmost part of the password field so just click that. If you're using anything else then please [edit] the question to add the full information.

Comment: "Standard Ubuntu greeter shows an "eye" symbol at the rightmost part of the password field so just click that". I clearly state in the OP that I don't want to click on the eye to see the input, I want to set letters to default rather than asterisks without having to click on the eye